# How can I get two remotes paired with the same fan receiver at the same time?

Tags: ceiling-fan, light, installation, remote-control

I bought a fan that came with one remote. But I want two.  I want one to keep by my bed, and one to fix to the wall by the entrance to the room.

The company I bought it from has sent me 4 remote and receiver packages.  But I can get any one remote to work with any one receiver.  But I cannot get two remotes to pair with the same receiver.  The way that I see it is:  The remotes don't pair to the receiver, but it's the receiver that pairs to the remote's frequency.  So the frequency that is given off by the remotes never change.  It's the receiver that changes.

It's really frustrating to have to walk into a dark room and look for the remote so that I can turn the light on the fan on.

I guess my question is: How can I get two remotes paired with the receiver at the same time?

Comment: Have you asked the company how to do it?

Comment: Yeah.  They don't seem to have a clue.  they just sent me a couple more hoping that I would luck up with two on the same frequency.  They said they don't recommend trying to pair two remotes.

Comment: It seems you have the answer from the company. What kind of fan? Stand, ceiling etc...? What is the pairing procedure?  What does the manual say? It's often not the frequency but a station code/id sent by the remote that is held as reference in the receiver.

Comment: There is no pairing involved. You set the dip switches on both sides to make them work together. The dip switches select the operating frequency which are designed in the remote and receiver. The factory operating frequency are chosen by the manufacturer. So if you get a second remote from the OEM you could use it.

Comment: There are no dip switches on the remote, or the receiver.  I took it apart and looked.  And I also asked.  This is definitely pairing involved.  I have four remotes.  I can pair them independently to the receiver.

Comment: IT's a ceiling fan with a light on it.  I don't car about conrtolling the fan so much with two remotes.  But the controlling the light is needed. Pairing procedure is:  Cut power to the fan/receiver.  (This must be done by actually stopping electricity from getting to it.) Cut power back on, then hold the power button down for 5 seconds on the remote you want to pair.  It works, but then the remote I was using before won't work.

Comment: The company is Parrot Uncle.  No phone communication or chat.  Only emails which get answered in a day or two.  And not on weekends.

Comment: If the system wasn't designed with multiple transmitters in mind, this may simply not be an option. My plan is to put in "smart switch" modules that are designed to live in the fan's housing, and which will tie into the rest of my home automation. (Have the modules, just forgot to order a Round Tuit.)

Comment: Yeah.  I'm thinking that I will have to guy a new system that is made to pair multiples and put that in.  I just didn't know if there is some way to actually reprogram the remote to emit the frequencies that I desire.  Yet I'm not smart enough to go about doing that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the company has indicated that doing what the OP wants is not a possibility with their fan design.

Comment: It's probably not different frequencies these days, but data packets with different addresses going over the same frequency. Most likely the same frequencies used by other home networks/remotes -- wifi, ZigBee, Bluetooth, etc.  Does the manufacturer let you connect to a phone or their internet service?

Comment: Have you tried pairing two remotes at eaxatly the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Options.

1. Most fan remotes include a wall holster so you can mount the remote on the wall near the door, grab the remote before bed and put it on your night table.   It's not exactly what you want but it delivers most of what you need most of the time with almost no effort.  Just stick the holster to the wall with mounting tape.
2. Buy a smart (wifi) fan control receiver.  Then you can buy all kinds of controllers for it and put them wherever you want.  You can use your phone.  You can use wall-mounted smart buttons, key fobs, bracelets and watches, Alexa and Google Home voice control, etc.  You could even set up [clap patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ny8-G8EoWOw) for different light and fan settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the cyber store and search for ceiling fan controls / 2 remotes.  A little searching will get you just what you need. A receiver for the fan that accepts a signal from both remotes.